# Calling multiple views from Uipopovercontroller list view contents

Tags: ios, uiview, uipopovercontroller

How can I call individual view controllers when I tap each row from my Pop Over List View in the most effective way? Meaning, I don't have to recode to build the Pop Over List View component in each of the individual view controllers, they can sort of share it like a navigation tool.

**What I Have Built**

I have built the pop over view controller list on my Main View Controller. 
This is the 1st view that gets loaded when appDidFinishLaunching is executed.
So, when we run the app, this is what we get:

Link to screenshot of the Pop Over List View:
http://s14.postimage.org/63k567vtd/image.png

For each row in the above Pop Over list, I have a method where I can put in the codes to:
1.  Identify which row was selected
2.  Based on the row selected, do any action, like NSLog and stuff
3.  All this codes sit in the Main View Controller

**The Requirement**

I am building a demo app, so all data is dummy data at the moment.

1. I need to call individual View Controller when each of the row in the Pop Over list is tapped.
2. Each of the View Controllers, will have their own set of data, own set of UI objects, its own XIB file.
3. So, if user taps on Applications, it must bring up the Applications XIB file and its functionality, followed by any navigations from here. If Application xib has a button that launches another view, this functionality should be in place too.
4. However, they all must have the same top Navigation Bar with the Pop Over list button, so user can tap that button and see the Pop Over list anytime in the app.

Please share your view. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking in to `UISplitViewController`. It is a component built by Apple to manage what it looks like you are trying to accomplish. Essentially, you set it up with 2 view controllers; the first (called the "master"), would be your table view. The second (called "detail") would be the view controller that gets switched out.

Once you explore it a little and are comfortable with the terminology, here's the general advice:

Inside the master table view controller's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, instantiate the appropriate view controller (based on the indexPath), and set it as the detail view controller, like this:

```
- (void)tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath {
    UIViewController *newDetailVC = // make and configure a new VC based on indexPath
    self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: self, newDetailVC, nil]];

}
```

Here are the appropriate links:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISplitViewController

and further (the later sections of): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html%23

Comment: It is worth noting that with this component, all of the UI related to showing and hiding the master section is handled for you, even changing it when rotating.